# Media Player android

Tags: android

Здравствуйте, у меня есть CardView и встроенный туда VideoView u MediaController, но при превью отображает только черный экран, как мне сделать отображение превью??(Видео загружается с сервера) или подскажите другой способ реализации??

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorCard"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <VideoView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/videoView" />

        <MediaController
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/mediaController" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Android Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text_default_material_light"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewVersion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

            android:text="Android Version"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text_default_material_light"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Не используйте превью. Если на девайсе/эмуляторе работает - значит всё нормально. Превью не сможет из сети что-то загрузить и отобразить

Comment: Но работает с лагами, то загружает видео-то нет, медиаконтр отображаться может сразу с 2-х видео. Или лучше писать свой меиаплеер используя MediaPlayer class???

Comment: Проблема может быть где угодно. На стороне сервера или у вас в коде или девайс маломощный или старая ОС или кастомная прошивка/лаунчер. Я как-то пробовал отображать видео по ссылке и проблем никаких не было. В любом случае проблема врятли в разметке экрана.

Comment: Android 5.1, у меня в карточке отображается сразу 11 видео, возможно, поэтому и тупит??может, есть другой способ реализации???

Comment: @ДмитрийКоверко, т.е. в одной разметке, одновременно на экране начинают проигрываться 11 видео?.. Таки да - это очень ресурсозатратная операция. Лучше не пытаться более одного видео за раз играть. С другой стороны я не вижу у вас в разметке 11 VideoView...

Comment: Нет, сразу видео не воспроизводится, но начинает загружаться,а в разметке их нету, зачем??я же использую cardview и создаю лист из карточек???протестирую еще с лучшим интернетом. возможно в этом причина и будет.

Comment: @ДмитрийКоверко, может быть поможет, если вы не будете сразу грузить видео, а делать это только по нажатию например